# django RuntimeError at /admin/users/user/1/change/, Single thread executor already being used, would deadlock

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I tried to make a chat app with `django-channels`.
But a RuntimeError occurs when I create a new `django-chanels` project and edit data in the admin site.

I'm not sure that I think the error occurred because I made several `django-channels` projects.

When I built my first project, WebSocket is not working, so I made another 2nd, 3rd, 4th project with `django-channels`. Now WebSocket is connected, but I have trouble with RuntimeError (Error message: Single thread executor already being user, would deadlock)

What can I do to fix this?

myproject/settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-is!$&voe3y058!2sus9egmxh@d!$)=l&o8_vl=m8zz!ap+d#a#"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "users.apps.UsersConfig",
    "channels",
    "core.apps.CoreConfig",
    "broadcasts.apps.BroadcastsConfig",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "busker.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "busker.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

ASGI_APPLICATION = "busker.asgi.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {"default": {"BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"}}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"
```

myproject/asgi.py

```
import os

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import broadcasts.routing

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        # Just HTTP for now. (We can add other protocols later.)
        "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(broadcasts.routing.websocket_urlpatterns)
        ),
    }
)
```

myapp/consumers.py

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = "Test-Room"

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

        print("Disconnected!")

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        receive_dict = json.loads(text_data)
        message = receive_dict["message"]

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name, {"type": "send.message", "message": message}
        )

    async def send_message(self, event):
        message = event["message"]

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": message}))
```

myapp/routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"", consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

Answer (score 16):

Either `pip install 'asgiref==3.3.4'` if you're remaining on `channels` version 3, or upgrade to `channels` version 4 (the issue is fixed in 4.0.0).

I noticed a similar `RuntimeError: Single thread executor already being used, would deadlock` after upgrading from `asgiref` 3.3.4 to 3.4.1.

This appears to be due to an [issue](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1722) in `channels` 3.0.4 where concurrent requests on the Django development server are intermittently failing. See also [Runtime Error Deadlock occurring randomly in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68343003/runtime-error-deadlock-occurring-randomly-in-django).

In 3.4.0, `asgiref` introduced additional deadlock checks. That's a good thing, but may have exposed an underlying issue in channels. From the [changelog](https://github.com/django/asgiref/blob/main/CHANGELOG.txt):

```
* Calling sync_to_async directly from inside itself (which causes a deadlock
  when in the default, thread-sensitive mode) now has deadlock detection.
```

If you do need to install asgiref >= 3.4.1, a workaround in development is to use `python manage.py runserver --noasgi`. This also has the benefit of being a little faster to reload.

Comment: Update: https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1722 is solved in Channels 4.