# Runtime Error Deadlock occurring randomly in Django

Tags: django

Running Django in Python 3.7.9. I am using channels so daphne is used but even when I using gunicorn the same results are obtained.

The error below is appearing randomly.

```
ERROR        2021-07-12 11:55:07,478 HTTP GET /static/customer/assets/js/jquery.min.js 500 [0.71, 127.0.0.1:55466]
ERROR        2021-07-12 11:55:07,479 Exception inside application: Single thread executor already being used, would deadlock
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/http.py", line 192, in __call__
    await self.handle(body_stream)
  File "/home/x/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 410, in __call__
    "Single thread executor already being used, would deadlock"
RuntimeError: Single thread executor already being used, would deadlock
```

I don't think this error has much to do with deadlock, but at times they are appearing together.

```
 ERROR        2021-07-12 11:55:07,478 HTTP GET
/static/customer/assets/js/jquery.min.js 500 [0.71, 127.0.0.1:55466]
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Don't have exact answer but the most important part of deadlock to understand what the resources you share between thread and when? it means that order of access to resource1 and resource2 into threads has different order. if you extend you question with this information then i would assume we found problem automatically

Comment: @MikeLazko The error is happening **SyncToAsync** class of the  the are checking  `self.deadlock_context and self.deadlock_context.get(False) , self.thread_sensitive_context and self.thread_sensitive_context.get( None)` if both the condition is false this error is been raised . I don't have clue on the order of resuorce allocation on the threads

Comment: I'm guessing the deadlock is related to a problem in your code and resources that the app serves as files (jquery.min.js). the check above just detail of implementation how lib detect deadlock.

Comment: Also there is second operation(request) which probably complete successfully but we lose it from our view. Because lib decided throw error for request GET jquery.min.js. Try to find second operation and it will be cause of this error

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this error by downgrading asgiref:

**requirements.txt**

```
asgiref==3.3.2
```

Comment: I had to downgrade to **asgiref==3.2.10**, I got error `TypeError: async_to_sync can only be applied to async functions.` from as asgiref on your version

Comment: Any Idea , What is the reason ??

Answer (score 0):

I solved this specific issues (occurred during fetch of static files) by running `python manage.py collectstatic` command. I assume, this way static files are not served by the same process. At least it solves my error.