# Python - Single thread executor already being used, would deadlock

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-queryset, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create an async view that accesses the DB and returns data with two separate queries.

```py
@sync_to_async
def get_tweets(request):
    return (Tweet.objects.
            annotate(full_text=Concat(F('title'), F('body'))).
            order_by(F('date').desc(nulls_last=True)).
            values('full_text', 'title', 'body', 'date',
                   tweet_id=F('uuid'), sent_to_app=F('sent')))


@sync_to_async
def get_users(request):
    return User.objects.filter(is_active=True).values('username', 'email',
                                                      full_name=Concat(F('first_name'), F('last_name')))


@sync_to_async
@csrf_exempt
@async_to_sync
async def async_view(request):
    funcs = [get_tweets, get_users]
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(func(request)) for func in funcs]
    data = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=FIRST_EXCEPTION)
    return JsonResponse({'data': data}, safe=False)
```

when debugging the code, before the response, I get an exception for every task in tasks:

```
RuntimeError('Single thread executor already being used, would deadlock')
```

so I can't collect the results, I don't understand why it's happening except it originated in asgiref.

I downgraded the asgiref version like said here:

[django RuntimeError at /admin/users/user/1/change/, Single thread executor already being used, would deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68208931/django-runtimeerror-at-admin-users-user-1-change-single-thread-executor-alrea)

but it didn't help. I don't understand if it comes from something in the way I set up the async code or from exception that's being raised in one of the functions and is hidden in the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You have a @sync_to_async decorator on an async function. Have you tried removing that?

You could even remove the @async_to_sync decorator too I believe as django can handle async view functions.

```
@csrf_exempt
async def async_view(request):
```